# Updating listview fragment on viewpager tab changes

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` using a `FragmentPagerAdapter` for displaying three tabs, each represented by its ow fragment. One of these fragments contains a list, that should be updated on switching / swiping to that tab. But I don't find any way to make it happen. I tried using the `onResume` method, but the fragments seem not to be paused and resumed on tab change. I also tried using `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` in my `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position)
{
    FragmentRefreshInterface currentFragment = (FragmentRefreshInterface) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(position);
    currentFragment.onRefreshed();
}
```

And in the fragment I use the following:

```
@Override
public void onRefreshed()
{
    List<Record> records = mRecordingService.getRecords();

    mRecordAdapter.clear();
    mRecordAdapter.add(record);
}
```

But using this code I can't access my `RecordingService` class that is used to provide the database functions (because mRecordingService seems to be null). I initialize it in the fragment like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mRecordingService = new RecordingService(getContext());
}
```

Comment: `Fragment` doesn't have an `onRefreshed()` method. What interface are you implementing to `@Override` this method from? (It would help a lot to show the exact class name that contains each method that you have shown here.)

Comment: What is the declaration for `mRecordAdapter`?

Comment: What is `record`? Where is it declared? I see a variable named `records` here, but not `record`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `onPageChangeListener` is the correct way to do it. I believe the reason why your code is not working, is because you are calling `getItem` on your pager adapter: `getItem()` actually returns a *new* instance of the fragment. In order to get the current instance, you use `instantiateItem()` (which returns a reference to the fragment actually being used).

Change your code to look something like this:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position)
{
    FragmentRefreshInterface currentFragment = (FragmentRefreshInterface) mSectionsPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(viewPager,position);
    currentFragment.onRefreshed();
}
```

And it should work.

Comment: That's what I was looking for :)

Comment: I don't think calling `onRefreshed()` directly is the solution. This appears to be a call back method implemented from some interface. Of course, simply changing the name of this method to a custom name would partially solve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that the code you have in `onRefreshed()` go in `onResume()` instead. `Fragment` doesn't have an `onRefreshed()` method. You must be implementing another interface that declares this method.

Since you are storing data in a database, you should be use a `CursorAdapter` or subclass such as `SimpleCursorAdapter`. If you do this correctly, the `ListView` will automatically update when you add a record to the database. Then the service can add records without needing to access the service from the fragment.

Answer (score -1):

In your MainActivity:

```
private FirstFragment firstFragment;
private WantedFragment wantedFragment;
private ThirdFragment thirdfragment;
```

In getItem

```
switch(postition){
   //return first, wanted, third fragments depending on position
}
```

onPageSelected:

```
if(position == 1) // position of the wanted fragment
wantedfragment.onRefreshed()
```

Comment: I'm skeptical about directly calling a method which appears to be a call back especially when a `ListView` will update automatically if it is implemented correctly.